# Do you include test files in code coverage?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, code-coverage

It seems that including test files in Code Coverage will overestimate the value.

But I can see that if you have code that is not used in the tests then it should be deleted.

So, are test files commonly included in the Code Coverage metric?

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible goals that people use code coverage analysis for.  And, there are many different ways to perform code coverage analysis.  For a specific goal, certain ways to use code coverage analysis make more sense than others.

You have mentioned one goal: Identify test code that is not used.  For this goal, a coverage analysis of the test code makes sense if the analysis shows you in detail which test code was executed and which was not.  On the other hand, a mere percentage like "87% of the test code was executed" will not help you.

Another, probably more typical goal is to use a code coverage percentage to judge the remaining effort needed for unit-testing to reach a certain coverage - or alternatively judge the risk due to the fact that a certain coverage goal was not reached.  I am not much in favor of such a use of coverage, but it's use is widespread.  Useful or not, for this goal at least the inclusion of the test code into the coverage metric does not make sense: The coverage of the test code is irrelevant for the remaining unit-testing effort or risk.

To conclude: There is no simple yes or no, because it depends on the goals.  However, it is certainly possible to perform different kinds of coverage analysis, or use the results in different ways for different purposes.